# How to resize a dynamically allocated array of polymorphic objects?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, polymorphism, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a dynamically allocated array of polymorphic objects that I would like to resize without using STL library (vectors, etc). I've tried moving the original to a temporary array, then deleting the original, then setting the original equal to the temporary, like this:

```
int x = 100;
int y = 150;

Animal **orig = new Animal*[x];
Animal **temp = new Animal*[y];

//allocate orig array
for(int n = 0; n < x; n++)
{
    orig[n] = new Cat();
}

//save to temp
for(int n = 0; n < x; n++)
{
    temp[n] = orig[n];
}

//delete orig array
for(int n = 0; n < x; n++)
{
    delete orig[n];
}
delete[] orig;

//store temp into orig
orig = temp;
```

**However, when I try to access the element for example:**

```
cout << orig[0]->getName();
```

I get a bad memeory alloc error:

```
Unhandled exception at at 0x768F4B32 in file.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x0033E598.
```

Comment: If you provided a minimal implementation of `Animal` so your code snippet could be compiled and run, it would be easier to track down the problem. Given that you're using C++, why on earth do you want to avoid `std::vector`?

Comment: Because people who only start using C++ are afraid of the Standard Library, that's why! STL is big, and scary, and unintelligible, and you not sure if it will behave the way you expect. So people start doing things on their own.

Comment: @Joker_vD That's really a bad argument (but I suspect that you know it).  `std::vector` should be learned well before `new`, or even C style arrays, since it is significantly easier to use than either.  (And he's doing an array `new`.  While learn something that has no practical use?)

Comment: Surely you should learn how to use STL before learning pointer stuff, but that's not how C++ courses are organized. And when you know about pointers and arrays, the first meeting with STL indeed makes you uneasy — because you try to imagine how it'll actually do its work with pointers and arrays, and you get confused, and just think, "Heck no, I'll do it on my own, I don't need any `std::` stuff". What I tell you is based on my talks with my buddies at the university who took the same programming courses.

Comment: Seconded @JamesKanze.  Consider "Accellerated C++" as an example text that does a good job of focusing on Standard Library components before getting all nitty gritty.

Comment: I *know* STL, thank you. I just explain why there are people who write on C++ without STL: it's a psychological thing.

Comment: @JohnDibling Everything I've heard about _Accelerated C++_ would concur.  Another book I've found very, very good is the latest Stroustrup; it has a different style, but also presents things in an intelligent order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//delete orig array
for(int n = 0; n < x; n++)
{
    delete orig[n];
}
```

For this particular case, **don't do this**. You are actually deleting the objects not the array. So all the objects in the temp array are pointing to invalid locations. Simply do `delete [] orig` to deallocate the original array.

Answer (score 1):

You are copying wrong. Instead of copying your temp array is simply pointing to the same location as that of the orig. Now when you delete the orig the temp pointers point to an invalid location.

```
//save to temp
for(int n = 0; n < x; n++)
{
    //temp[n] = orig[n];
    // Try this instead
    strcpy(temp[n], orig[n]);
}
```